# Reference Figures in the body differently as from inside the appendix

Tags: labels, cleveref, appendix

I want to reference Figures, Tables etc. from the body differently when they are placed in the appendix.
However, inside the appendix, they should be referenced as usual.

Here is a small working example of what I mean and how it should look like:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\RequirePackage[capitalise, noabbrev]{cleveref}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Chapter 1}
Here I reference a picture from the body: \cref{fig:image_in_body}
% Here I reference a picture from the body: Figure 1.1
% Exactly as I want it

Here I reference a picture from the appendix: \cref{fig:image_in_appendix}
% Here I reference a picture from the appendix: Figure A.1
% Here it should look like this: Here I reference a picture from the appendix: Appendix A.1

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-golden}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:image_in_body}
\end{figure}


\appendix
\chapter{Appendix}
Here I reference a picture from the body: \cref{fig:image_in_body}
% Here I reference a picture from the body: Figure 1.1
% Exactly as I want it

Here I reference a picture from the appendix: \cref{fig:image_in_appendix}
% Here I reference a picture from the appendix: Figure A.1
% Exactly as I want it

\begin{figure}
    \includegraphics{example-image-golden}
    \caption{Caption}
    \label{fig:image_in_appendix}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

I have no idea how I can achieve this.